# Модель категорий в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

подскажите как на Django организовать категории например для такого шаблона

```html
{% for category in main_category %}

    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children has-mega-menu"><a href="#">{{category.name}}
    </a>
      <div class="mega-menu">
        <div class="mega-wrap">
          <div class="mega-column">
            <ul class="mega-item mega-features">

              <li><a href="product-listing.html">{{category.brand}}</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">FEATURES SHOES</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">BEST SELLERS</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">NOW TRENDING</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">SUMMER ESSENTIALS</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">MOTHER'S DAY COLLECTION</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">FAN GEAR</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="mega-column">
            <h4 class="mega-heading">{{category.brand}}</h4>
            <ul class="mega-item">
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">{{category.brand}}</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Running</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Training & Gym</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Basketball</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Football</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Soccer</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Baseball</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="mega-column">
            <h4 class="mega-heading">CLOTHING</h4>
            <ul class="mega-item">
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Compression & Nike Pro</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Tops & T-Shirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Polos</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Jackets & Vests</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Pants & Tights</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Shorts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="mega-column">
            <h4 class="mega-heading">Accessories</h4>
            <ul class="mega-item">
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Compression & Nike Pro</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Tops & T-Shirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Polos</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Jackets & Vests</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Pants & Tights</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Shorts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="mega-column">
            <h4 class="mega-heading">BRAND</h4>
            <ul class="mega-item">
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">NIKE</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Adidas</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">Dior</a></li>
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">B&G</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    {%endfor%}
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown"><a href="#">News</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown"><a href="blog-grid.html">Blog-grid</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="blog-grid.html">Blog Grid 1</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="blog-grid-2.html">Blog Grid 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="blog-list.html">Blog List</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown"><a href="#">Contact</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us #1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us #2</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Я делал так:

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Основная категория')
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_text
```

Категория без `parent` считается главной, категория с указанным `parrent` считается подкатегорией.

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    main_category = Category.objects.filter(parent=None)
    subcategory = Category.objects.exclude(parent=None)
    return render(request, 'шаблон.html', {'main_category': main_category, 'subcategory': subcategory})
```

html:

```
<div class="mega-column">
{% for category in main_category %}
    {% if category.parent == None %}
        <h4 class="mega-heading">{{ category }}</h4>
    {% endif %}
    <ul class="mega-item">
        {% for subcategories in subcategory %}
            {% if subcategories.parent.id == category.id %}
                <li><a href="product-listing.html">{{ subcategories }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вроде работает, только в Html запутался , подскажите как расставить а то сайдбар уехал

Comment: А так что бы до 3х, допустим Мужское -> Одежда-> Футболки ?